# How to verify if the user input data exist in Firestore document in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do an app where users have to input their friend's invitation code before being friends with each other. How do I check and verify if the code is exist and not equal to the current user's code? Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQMtF.png) of my firestore database:

[image]

Here is my code attempt that doesn't work. currentText refer to the user input eg. 106407.

```
Future<void> verify(currentText) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('code', arrayContainsAny: [currentText])
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print(doc["name"]);
          });
        });
  }
```

Actually, I have no idea on what to put after .get() so I just go with printing the name of the user which their code equal to the currentText.
I'm also thinking about creating a sub-collection called 'friends' under each users so that I can display the user friend list containing their friends' name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `code` field is not an array, so you `arrayContainsAny` won't work on it. Instead, you'll want to use `isEqualTo`:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('code', isEqualTo: currentText)
```